# Approximating $f/|f|$ using compactly supported functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be $\mu$ locally integrable, where $\mu$ is a Radon measure (on $\mathbb{R}^n$).

How to construct compactly supported continuous functions $\varphi_k:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $\text{spt}\varphi_k\subseteq A$ and $|\varphi_k|\leq 1$ so that $$\int \varphi_k\cdot f\mathrm{d}\mu\to \int_A |f|\mathrm{d}\mu$$

I need this to show that total variation of bounded linear functional $\varphi\mapsto \int \varphi\cdot f \mathrm{d}\mu$ is equal to $|f|\mathrm{d}\mu$.